# WordPress custom post type pagination 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, post, pagination, taxonomy

I am trying to get pagination working on a custom theme.

I have a post type with custom taxonomies and I have pagination for those custom taxonomies and that works fine.

However on another part of the site I have another custom post type; I am trying to paginate through the posts in this post type. Currently the posts are in a custom taxonomy also in this post type, the custom taxonomy behaves like a category.

The URL structure is http://www.domain.com/latest-news/, however when I go to http://www.domain.com/latest-news/2/ I get a 404 error, this is the problem.

Here is my code (sorry it's so long):

```
<?php
                $numCats = 0;
                $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
                $posts_per_page = 5;
                $offset = ($posts_per_page * $paged - $posts_per_page);
                $taxonomies = array(
                    'latest-cat'
                    );
                $args = array(
                  'hide_empty' => false,
                  'parent' => 0,
                  'orderby' => 'id',
                  'order' => 'DESC',
                  'paged' => $paged
                  );
                $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'latest_news_item',
                    'oserby' => 'id',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'latest-cat',
                        'terms' => $term->term_id
                        )
                      )
                    );
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    while ($wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
                    $numCats++;
                    endwhile;
                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'latest_news_item',
                    'parent' => 115,
                    'orderby' => 'id',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                    'offset' => 0,
                    'paged' => $paged
                    );
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
                while ($wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="news-events-item">
                    <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
                    <p class="summary"><?php echo wp_trim_words($content, '30', '...'); ?><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more">More</a></p>
                </div>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                } ?>
```

The $numCats variable is just to count the number of posts so that I can set up the pagination links, and that part works.

Thank you

Comment: Can you try accessing http://www.domain.com/latest-news/page/2/ and see if that works?

Comment: You have a typo here too: `'oserby' => 'id'` - it might be the cause, not sure.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ I have fixed the typo and unfortunately that didn't help, thanks for spotting it though, and I tried going to that page but that is also a 404.

The weird thing is that the url structure is the same as the pagination that is working in a different part of the site however it doesn't work this time.

Comment: your $paged variable should also read $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; - note the 'paged' not 'page'. you should also be resetting your queries before starting another with wp_reset_query()

Comment: @johnnyd23 I have tried with paged instead of page but it is still not working. I have a wp_reset_query just before this lot of php, whereabouts should I be adding it inside that php?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this for myself in this way:

On an archive page of the custom post type "blog".

```
                $paged = 1;
                if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');

                query_posts( '&post_type=blog&paged=' . $paged );

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'blog',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'orderby'           => 'date',
                    'order'             => 'DEST',
                    'posts_per_page'                => '1',

                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

- this is the classic loop with added arguments for post type "blog" and added "Paged" attribute.
  And obviously these points:

  ```
  $paged = 1;
                if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');

                query_posts( '&post_type=blog&paged=' . $paged );
  ```

At the end, **outside of the loop** is the pagination output from functions.php

```
            <?php echo pagination($loop->max_num_pages); ?>
```

In functions.php is the permalink modification and also modification of the "posts_per_page" set to ONE post, so you can test the pagination.

```html
function paginate() {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
    $pagination = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => true,
        'type' => 'plain'
    );
    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
    if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
    echo paginate_links( $pagination );
}
function portfolio_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'blog' ) $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 1;
    return $query;
}
if ( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'portfolio_posts_per_page' );
```

```
And as last here is the pagination code which is used on the archive page outside of the loop.

**used with bootstrap 5.0**


    

function pagination($pages = '', $range = 1)
{
    $showitems = ($range * 2) + 1;

    global $paged;
    if (empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if ($pages == '') {
        global $the_query;
    $pages = $the_query->max_num_pages;
    if (!$pages) {
        $pages = 1;
    }
}

if (1 != $pages) {
    echo "<nav aria-label=\"...\">
        <ul class=\"pagination\">";
    if ($paged > 2 && $paged > $range + 1 && $showitems < $pages)
        echo "
                 <li class=\"page-item \">
              <a class=\"page-link\" href=\"" . get_pagenum_link(1) . "\">První</a>
            </li>";
    if ($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages)

        echo "
              <li class=\"page-item \">
              <a class=\"page-link\" href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($paged - 1) . "\">Předchozí</a>
            </li>";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if (1 != $pages && (!($i >= $paged + $range + 1 || $i <= $paged - $range - 1) || $pages <= $showitems)) {
             echo ($paged == $i) ? "<li class=\"page-item active\"><a class=\"page-link\" href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "\">" . $i . "</a></li>" : "<li class=\"page-item\"><a class=\"page-link\" href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "\">" . $i . "</a></li>";

        }
    }

    if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages)
       echo "
              <li class=\"page-item \">
              <a class=\"page-link\" href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1) . "\">Další</a>
            </li>";
    if ($paged < $pages - 1 && $paged + $range - 1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages)
        echo "
                 <li class=\"page-item \">
              <a class=\"page-link\" href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($pages) . "\">Poslední</a>
            </li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";

    //echo "<div class='all_pages text-muted'><small>Stránek " . $pages . "</small></div>";
}
```

}

I hope it helps, it works for me.

(sorry for formating, stack overflow editor is totall bull...)